# c# update current time,days,date

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    todayDate.Text=DateTime.Now.toString();
}
```

Output

> 10:28AM 9/28/2011

the current time is never update, the result is static, how do i set a interval in c# in order to update current time?

updated information

this is my ajax updated timer code

```
  <ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server">
```

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="TimedPanel" updatemode="Conditional">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="UpdateTimer" eventname="Tick" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" id="DateStampLabel" />
```

and i called it by using

```
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateStampLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString() + "  "+DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString(); 


}
```

output is exactly what i want, but the effect not exactly what i want, cause when user clicked on some button,the label will blink, this like telling the user the page is reloading, so i wondering is that any idea can deliver update time from server? or just refresh partial pages?

Comment: You want to do this in Page_Load and/or a postback?

Comment: It would be better to use JavaScript to implement this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason it doesn't update is because the ASP.Net is server code that is generating HTML which is presented in the browser.

The browser sends a request to your server, the server executes your page logic on one of it's threads, your code generates output (which in your case, setting the today.Data.Text is creating html in the output buffer), the response is sent to the client and the browser shows that html.  You're done.  The request was fulfilled.

You either need to keep refreshing that page (bad - old full refresh server generated page model) or have javascript code that runs in the browser.  Checkout Ajax patterns for that.

Hope that gives insight as to why :)

Comment: If you need the server time, you can also have the server expose a web service or rest method for it's time.  Don't have the server do presentation because then it needs to refresh.  Instead, do an ajax style javascript refresh and update the dom document inline.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ajax Extension` controls ([UpdatePanel, Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398874.aspx)).

Comment: Ajax seems a little overkill for this, doesn't it?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer - I believe so but  if he/she wants to get server datetime then I think this is the basic way.

Comment: It's possible to deliver the initial time from the server, and just use javascript on the client to increment, though.

Comment: You can also make the server expose a web service or rest method.  Have the ajax client call that on a timer.  Should be fast and avoids the server from rendering and refreshing ...

Comment: @ChrisFarmer - I appreciate that. Buddy we know very well. There are number of possible ways do to same thing.

Comment: @AVD: Agreed :)  ^Chris Farmer: I'm not sure what ajax being overkill.  Ajax at it's roots is just client side javascripts doing web requests client side (not refreshing the server page).  If you need the servers time, then you need to request it. Now, if you're talking about pulling in Ajax frameworks then maybe ... ;)

Comment: Not trying to be a smartass. It just appeared to me that the OP wanted the current time to just be "live" on his/her page, and IMO it's least complicated to do that on the client. You're right that legit server uses are possible.

Comment: actually i had tried to use ajax as well,but the performance not really good,every time when i clicked on some button,the updater timer will blink , i dun really like to blink effect so i was thinking is that any way can deliver update time from server?

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested you need to use a client-side script to update the values in realtime, if this is your intention.  Searching for 'JavaScript clock' or 'Ajax clock' should give you some cut-n-paste code, or look into some Ajax examples in their toolkit.